# React + Typescript: Properly Typing General Component with Props that have Functions with Optional Generic Types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I had(and still am having) trouble wording this question so sorry if it is hard to understand.

**Question:**
How do I properly type a general component with props that have functions with optional generic types,
so that I can create both components that use and do not use the optional generic types?

**For Example(code can also be viewed in codesandbox):**
codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-haslett-ojjw6

Let's say I want a search form with 1 basic search field and optional search field(s).
Also, the optional search field(s) return different but specific types of data based on how it is used.
We know the specfic type beforehand so we're going to call them `A` and `B`.

So I decided to create the following general component name `Search`:

```
// the specific types of data that the optional search field(s) return
export type OptionalSearchTypeA = {
  keyA1: string
  keyA2: string
}
export type OptionalSearchTypeB = {
  keyB1: string
}

// a union type of all types of optional search field(s) to restrict the type in generics
// allow undefined since it is optional
export type OptionalSearchType = OptionalSearchTypeA | OptionalSearchTypeB | undefined

// the search state used in the search component
export type SearchStateType<T extends OptionalSearchType = undefined> = {
  search: string
  optionalSearch?: T
}

// props for the actual search component 
export type SearchProps<T extends OptionalSearchType = undefined> = {
  label: string
  searchState: SearchStateType<T>
  onChange: (searchState: SearchStateType<T>) => void
  hasOptionalSearch: boolean
}

// actual Search component
export const Search = <T extends OptionalSearchType = undefined>({
  label,
  searchState,
  onChange,
  hasOptionalSearch,
}: SearchProps<T>) => {
  const handleChangeSearch = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => onChange({ ...searchState, search: e.target.value })

  return (
    <label id={label}>
      <div>{label}</div>
      <input id={label} value={searchState.search} onChange={handleChangeSearch} />
      {/* hasOptionalSearch && (generate optional input field based on searchState.optionalSearch) */}
    </label>
  )
}
```

Now, in the actual app, the Search component for the specific type `A` and `B` are commonly used in multiple places and their UI differ greatly from each other.
Hence I decided to wrap this Search component for each specific type `SearchA` and `SearchB`.

So here is the code for those specific components `SearchA` and `SearchB`:

```
// components/specific/SearchA
export type SearchAProps = {
  label: string
  searchState: SearchStateType<OptionalSearchTypeA | undefined>
  onChange: (searchState: SearchStateType<OptionalSearchTypeA | undefined>) => void
  hasOptionalSearch: boolean
}

// simplified in this example but UI differs greatly from SearchB
export const SearchA = (props: SearchAProps) => <Search<OptionalSearchTypeA | undefined> {...props} />


// components/specific/SearchB
export type SearchBProps = {
  label: string
  searchState: SearchStateType<OptionalSearchTypeB | undefined>
  onChange: (searchState: SearchStateType<OptionalSearchTypeB | undefined>) => void
  hasOptionalSearch: boolean
}

// simplified in this example but UI differs greatly from SearchA
export const SearchB = (props: SearchBProps) => <Search<OptionalSearchTypeB | undefined> {...props} />
```

Now when I use it in the app...I get an error...

```
// searchState for components for both specific type and with optional and without optional
export const A_initSearchStateWithOptional: SearchStateType<OptionalSearchTypeA> = {
  search: '',
  optionalSearch: {
    keyA1: '',
    keyA2: '',
  },
}

export const A_initSearchStateWithoutOptional: SearchStateType = {
  search: '',
}

export const B_initSearchStateWithOptional: SearchStateType<OptionalSearchTypeB> = {
  search: '',
  optionalSearch: {
    keyB1: '',
  },
}

export const B_initSearchStateWithoutOptional: SearchStateType = {
  search: '',
}

export const App = () => {
  const [A_searchStateWithOptional, setA_searchStateWithOptional] = useState(A_initSearchStateWithOptional)
  const [A_searchStateWithoutOptional, setA_searchStateWithoutOptional] = useState(A_initSearchStateWithoutOptional)
  const [B_searchStateWithOptional, setB_searchStateWithOptional] = useState(B_initSearchStateWithOptional)
  const [B_searchStateWithoutOptional, setB_searchStateWithoutOptional] = useState(B_initSearchStateWithoutOptional)

  // typescript tells me that onChange has a type mismatch, but I know that it will return the type I expect
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SearchA
        label="Search A with Optional"
        searchState={A_searchStateWithOptional}
        onChange={setA_searchStateWithOptional}
        hasOptionalSearch={true}
      />
      <SearchA
        label="Search A without Optional"
        searchState={A_searchStateWithoutOptional}
        onChange={setA_searchStateWithoutOptional}
        hasOptionalSearch={false}
      />
      <SearchB
        label="Search B with Optional"
        searchState={B_searchStateWithOptional}
        onChange={setB_searchStateWithOptional}
        hasOptionalSearch={true}
      />
      <SearchB
        label="Search B without Optional"
        searchState={B_searchStateWithoutOptional}
        onChange={setB_searchStateWithoutOptional}
        hasOptionalSearch={false}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<SearchStateType<OptionalSearchTypeA>>>' is not assignable to type '(searchState: SearchStateType<OptionalSearchTypeA | undefined>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'searchState' are incompatible.
    Type 'SearchStateType<OptionalSearchTypeA | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<SearchStateType<OptionalSearchTypeA>>'.
      Type 'SearchStateType<OptionalSearchTypeA | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'SearchStateType<OptionalSearchTypeA>'.
        Type 'OptionalSearchTypeA | undefined' is not assignable to type 'OptionalSearchTypeA'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'OptionalSearchTypeA'.ts(2322)
index.ts(6, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SearchAProps'
```

It tells me that I can't assign `OptionalSearchType* | undefined` to `OptionalSearchType*`.

I know that I'll be receiving the `OptionalSeachType*` for the Search component with `hasOptionalSearch={true}` while I know it will be `undefined` for ones that have `hasOptionalSearch={false}`. Must I still type them with `useState<OptionalSearchType* | undefined>`? I want to simply say that it is `useState<SearchStateType<OptionalSearchType*>>` or `useState<SearchStateType<undefined>>` becuase I know that's what will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make the onChange function less specific than what TS infers by supplying your type to useState

`useState<OptionalSearchTypeA | undefined>(A_initSearchStateWithOptional)`

A discriminated union type might be what you're looking for.

```
type SearchTypes = {
  hasOptional: true;
  optionalSearh: {
    type: string;
  };
} | {
  hasOptional: false;
};
```

Using this type will tell typescript that when hasOptional=true, the field optionalSearch must exist on the object.

Comment: Thank you for the response! While your answer did resolve the type error.
I had to rephrased my question since it didn't quite ask the question I wanted to ask. sorry  
I know that I'll be receiving the `OptionalSeachType*` for the components with `hasOptionalSearch={true}` while I know it will be `undefined` for ones that have `hasOptionalSearch={false}`. Must I still type them with `useState<OptionalSearchType* | undefined>`? I want to simply say that it is useState<SearchStateType<OptionalSearchType*>>` or `useState<SearchStateType<undefined>>` since I know that's what will be returned.

Comment: Still trying to understand the quest. Added another answer.